# Duda con la funcion SUM en Mysql

Tags: mysql

Hola espero que me puedan ayudar con lo siguiente 
digamos que tengo esta tabla

```
Productos->Nombre de la tabla
Nombre->campo
Valor->campo
```

con estos registros

Tomate->500
Cebolla->400
y tenga esta consula

```
 `SELECT SUM(Valor)as Total FROM Productos;`
```

eso me retornaria que el primer registro vale 900, me hace la suma bien pero no me muestra todos los registros y me da a entender que el tomate vale 900

lo intente asi tambien

```
`SELECT Nombre,Valor,SUM(Valor)as Total FROM Productos GROUP BY Nombre;`
```

con esa consulta si me muestra todos los registros y los valores pero no me hace la suma.

Ahora bien lo que intento es que me muestra todos los registros y la suma para saber que es lo que estoy sumando

Muchas Gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Veamos... si tus productos son únicos en esa tabla (que sería lo más lógico):

```
 CREATE TABLE productos(nombre text, valor integer);
 INSERT INTO productos(nombre, valor)
 VALUES ('Tomate', 500)
  , ('Cebolla', 400)
  , ('Lechuga', 200);

| Nombre  | valor |
------------------
| Tomate  | 500   |
| Cebolla | 400   |
| Lechuga | 200   |
```

Y quieres mostrar cuánto valdría comprar el total de los productos listados para obtener algo como

```
| Nombre  | valor | Total
-------------------------
| Tomate  | 500   | 1100
| Cebolla | 400   | 1100
| Lechuga | 200   | 1100
```

La respuesta depende de tu versión de MySQL.

---

### MySQL v8

En la versión 8 puedes usar una window function:

```
SELECT nombre, valor, SUM(valor) OVER () AS total FROM productos;
```

**<kbd>[Ver ejemplo completo en DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=46fea121cba64e41bdb6395e0621f569)</kbd>**

---

### MySQL 5.7 o anterior

En esta versión no hay window functions, y seleccionar una función agregada sin declarar el criterio de agrupación, o listar un campo no agregado que no forme parte de un criterio de agrupación *puede funcionar* dado los settings de MySQL, pero formarlmente debiera tirar un error:

```
SELECT nombre, valor, SUM(valor)as Total FROM productos GROUP BY nombre;
```

> Expression #2 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains
>   nonaggregated column 'valor' which is not functionally dependent on
>   columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with
>   sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Si relajas esta condición:

```
SET SESSION sql_mode=(SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode,'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY',''));     
SELECT nombre, valor, SUM(valor)as Total FROM productos GROUP BY nombre;
```

El motor entenderá que todos los campos no agregados son parte del group by, y obtendrás un resultado que no es lo que buscabas:

```
| Nombre  | valor | Total
-------------------------
| Tomate  | 500   | 500
| Cebolla | 400   | 400
| Lechuga | 200   | 200
```

La manera correcta de hacerlo en MySQL 5.7 es

```
SELECT  nombre, valor, suma.total  FROM productos
  JOIN (SELECT SUM(valor) as total FROM productos) as suma
```

**<kbd>[Ver ejemplo completo en DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=9495c2a289e3c509b8a56c40e7d4f128)</kbd>**

Comment: muchas gracias amigo ahora quiero me digas algo digamos que quiera colocar esto en php veo que el total se repite quedaria algo feo la verdad ,si yo pongo 2 consultas en php una para hacer un select y la otra para hacer la suma lo podre acomodar?

Comment: Claro que puedes. Depende como quieras mostrarlo y, en la práctica, si vas a usar PHP puedes usar una consulta simple a la tabla e ir sumando tú para obtener el total